# Obtain specific data with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have different texts which aren't well formatted, therefore I need a pattern which works with all of them and return some specific elements (text) from it. Let's say I have this text:

```
"AL TEST232    KW     12*/13*/17 TEST kw16TEST123 kw 15*"
```

and I want my preg_match_all() to return something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => AL TEST232
            [1] => 12/13/17
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => TEST
            [1] => 16
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => TEST123
            [1] => 15
        )
)
```

Is this possible with a single pattern?

Comment: What is fixed and what is dynamic in above text?

Comment: @anubhava Essentially there is some pattern which is: (sometext)(kw)(number). The first part might be composed from different words and numbers. The second part is either "kw" or "KW". The third part should be a simple number (e.g.: 12) or as set of numbers divided by a slash (e.g.: 12/13/14). The third part might also containt the asterisk character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
preg_match_all('~(\w[\s\w]*?\w)\s*kw\s*([\d/*]+)~', $input, $matches);
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW1kJ0/1)

Comment: Great. One last thing, is it possible to exclude the asterisk character when it come right after a number in the third part?

Comment: Ok, but this will work only if I want to exclude the last `*`, if you check my question you'll see that the asterisk character is also present in other places. Is it still possible to exclude it using one pattern or should I do this in two different steps?

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I'm not clear...essentially I want to hide/exlude the `*` from the first match, and of course from the numbers after the `kw` in all the other matches.

Comment: Hmm in that case you will need to run `str_replace` or `preg_replace` after this `preg_match_all` call (I have reverted to original solution).